# Ploneformgen and regular expression

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I would like to use regular expression in  the form created using ploneformgen 1.7. I am using plone 4.1. In the custom validation of a text field.

How do I use the regular expression?

I tried the following:

```
python: import re; test(value==re.search(r'[123]'), False, 'Needs to be number 1 or 2 or 3')
```

but it gives me error and hence cannot validate.
I want value should be 1 or 2 or 3. I am able to use the expression as

```
python: test(value=='1' or value=='2' or value=='3', False, 'Needs to be number 1 or 2 or 3')
```

BUT I would like to use regular expressions. Please guide.

Comment: I don't know too much about Plone, but it seems that you are comparing a MatchObject with a string. Perhaps you need to access to `.group(0)` to get the string that matched?

Comment: @OscarMederos: These are restricted python expressions and you cannot import `re` anyway..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of packages and types that you may use in through-the-web scripts, TALES "python:" expressions, PFG overrides and PFG script adapters is limited to those available in Restricted Python. Restricted Python is deliberately very conservative in which modules and types it makes available.

You may expand the list with explicit "allow" declarations made in a Python package included in your egg list. A sample of such a package is [available in the github collective](https://github.com/collective/collective.localfunctions), and includes several modules and types that I've found particularly useful in PloneFormGen, including re.

You will still not be able to "import re" in a TALES expression, but you will be able to use re in a TTW script, which may be used as a PFG validator.

Answer (score 3):

Per http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/ScriptingZope.html, you cannot use regular expressions in TALES, since they are forbidden by Restricted Python.

Answer (score -1):

You actually need 2 parameters for the search method.

You should use this way: `import re; test(re.search(r'[123]', value), False, 'Needs to be number 1 or 2 or 3')`

Comment: I test it this way:

    `>>>import re
    >>>value = '3'
    >>>bool(re.search(r'[123]', value))
    >>>True`
 you should try using bool function

Comment: @rberbabe it is a bool value that is returned only. Anyways thanx for your efforts

Comment: @rbernabe: This is a restricted Python expression environment, not full Python.